# Is 60FPS to be considered only during Web animations?

Tags: html, css, web, web-performance

I am going through tutorials and articles on how to achieve 60FPS for web animations. I am working on the web performance on a site and was wondering whether 60FPS is valid on the idle page too?

Eg:- While scrolling page I see theres some drop on the frame rate due to some long running script which was triggered on scroll events.

I might sound too noob here, but wanted to understand from others where all the 60FPS is expected.

So I wanted to understand more whether a good performing site should always achieve 60FPS even on idle state too?

I googled around and mostly found 60FPS was measured for Web Animations only.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering (emphasis my own):

> **60fps and Device Refresh Rates**
>
> Most devices today refresh their screens 60 times a second. If there’s an animation or transition running, ***or the user is scrolling the pages***, the browser needs to match the device’s refresh rate and put up 1 new picture, or frame, for each of those screen refreshes.